# Iframe is empty in Firefox but works fine in Chrome

Tags: django, firefox, nginx, iframe, docker-compose

I have a django app that I'm trying to embed on a page with a different domain. Let's say my django app is hosted at `https://myapp.io`, and the page I'm trying to embed it in is at `example.com`.

Here's what my iframe looks like:

```
<iframe src="https://myapp.io" style="border: medium none; min-height: 350px; overflow: hidden;" id="myIframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Here is the actual request+response that is sent when the iframe loads in Chrome. This matches exactly the request that is sent in Firefox. The `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` was set to `ALLOW-FROM myapp.io`.

[image: request screenshot]

The Request headers that were left out were:

```
Host:myapp.io
Referer:https://example.com/path/to/current/page
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
```

This request works in Chrome and the contents of the iframe display correctly. However, in Firefox, the iframe is empty.

Chrome displays this console error upon page load:

> Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading
>   'https://myapp.io: 'ALLOW-FROM MYAPP.IO' is not a recognized
>   directive. The header will be ignored.

In Firefox, I can replace my `myapp.io` URL with `https://w3schools.com`, the contents of `w3schools.com` displays in the iframe.

However, in the Network tab of the developer tools in Firefox shows the iframe's contents have been received by the browser. It just never makes it into the iframe for some reason.

How do I fix this and allow Firefox to display my Iframe?

**EDIT**

To rule out any funny business with JavaScript or anything else, I have set my iframe to load page with the following content, with no change in Firefox's behavior.

```
<html>
  <body>hi</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2**

Since I'm deploying my Django app with docker-compose, I figured I'd post my config files.

### nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile        on;
  #tcp_nopush     on;

  keepalive_timeout  65;

  #gzip  on;

  upstream app {
    server django:5000;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    charset     utf-8;

    location / {
      # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
      root /usr/share/nginx;
      try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    # cookiecutter-django app
    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options 'ALLOW-FROM myapp.io';
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass   http://app;
    }
  }
}
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  postgres_data: {}
  postgres_backup: {}
  static: {}

services:
  postgres:
    build: ./compose/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_backup:/backups
    env_file: .env

  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/django/Dockerfile
    user: django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    command: /gunicorn.sh
    volumes:
      - static:/app/powerschool_apps/static/public
    env_file: .env

  nginx:
    build: ./compose/nginx
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - static:/usr/share/nginx/static

    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:80"


  redis:
    image: redis:latest
```

### django config

```
# SECRET CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key
# Raises ImproperlyConfigured exception if DJANGO_SECRET_KEY not in os.environ
SECRET_KEY = env('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')

# This ensures that Django will be able to detect a secure connection
# properly on Heroku.
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# SECURITY CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.security
# and https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/#run-manage-py-check-deploy
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = env.bool(
    'DJANGO_SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS', default=True)
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = env.bool(
    'DJANGO_SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF', default=True)
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOW-FROM myapp.io'
```

Comment: setting a min-height won't help in an iframe because the iframe content will not expand the iframe size, you need to set a fixed height

Comment: I didn't mention that I'm using the [iFrameResizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) library to keep the iFrame properly resized. I only set the min-height to make the transition from fixed-height to `iFrameResize`d a bit smoother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the protocol to the `ALLOW-FROM` header.

Instead of

`proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options 'ALLOW-FROM myapp.io';`

it should be

`proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options 'ALLOW-FROM https://myapp.io';`

Comment: Please note that the X-Frame-Options is deprecated now. Use the frame-ancestors directive of the Content-Security-Policy HTTP header instead. Further infos [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)